# Runtime.getRuntime().exec does not find the default python version

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I wanted to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to execute a simple python script `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test.py")` which contains only few imports, but it failed with error 1. I traced the error, and I found out that some libraries were not found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/firetiti/NetBeans/FiReTiTiLiB/Test.py", line 6, in <module>
from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

When I executed the same script into a terminal, everything was fine. So I replaced `python` with the absolute path to python `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/somewhere/in/my/computer/python3.6 test.py")`, and it worked.

So it seems that `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`does not use the configured version of python. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `exec("python test.py")` in Java, will try to resolve `python` to an executable file in the same way as any other application does.

Assuming that you are using UNIX, Linux or Mac OSX, the sequence is roughly as follows:

1. The JVM performs a `fork` syscall to create a child process.  The child process inherits the environment variables of the parent (JVM) process.
2. The child process performs an exec syscall, passing it the command name, arguments and environment variables.
3. If the command name is a simple name, the syscall attempts to resolving the name to a pathname by searching the directories on the command search path for an executable file; i.e. one with the appropriate execute permission set.
4. If an executable is found, it is either loaded into the child process or interpreted as a script, depending on its signature.

In your case, it is step 3 that is not working.  Specifically, it finds the wrong version of `python` on the search path. The search path is determined by the `PATH` environment variable ... as inherited from the parent JVM.

So, if you get different results in an interactive shell and from Java, that most likely means that they have different `PATH` variables.  That is the first thing to check.  For example, in your Java application, see what this outputs:

```
  System.out.println(System.environ().get("PATH"));
```

and check that the first `python` command it would find is the version that you want.

Possible solutions:

- Set `PATH` appropriately before starting the JVM
- Use `ProcessBuilder` to execute the external command with a modified environment
- Use an absolute pathname for the `python` command.
- If this is Python 2 vs 3, give the command name as `python2` or `python3`.  (A typical Linux package etc will link from `python2` and `python3` to the correct executables.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer. I used `System.getenv("PATH")` to display the variable, and indeed lot of things are missing, but they are present when I run the command `echo $PATH` into a terminal. So it seems that my best option would be the one I've already used (your third bullet point "absolute pathname").